# Facebook crawler in python

Tags: facebook, api

i am trying to make a Facebook recon tool in python
Its main property is to gather people that work on a company received in input.

I have installed the Facebook python Api.

I manage to get an Api token but i do not have any idea how to make the search??

Answer (score 0):

Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

You can only search for people by name.